# How to use a looping variable inside a callback in JavaScript/TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've a method like this in my ts file

```js
getInitialBatches() {
    var i = 0;
    for (var dto of this.transferDTO.stockMovesDTOs) {
        i++;

        this.queryResourceService
            .getBatchIdUsingGET(this.batchParams)
            .subscribe((data) => {
                this.allBatches[i] = data;
            });
    }
}
```

Since `getBacthIdUsingGET` is a callback, It is not functioning the way I want.loop control variable `i` gets increased by more than 1 by the time call back gets invoked so I'm not able to put values into every index of `allBatches` array, Value is getting placed into random indexes. how to solve this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with vars in loops, and it was specifically part of the let specification that lets this work properly.
https://wesbos.com/for-of-es6

In general, it's best practice to avoid using vars due to their weirdness in certain instances and their scoping mechanisms.

```js
getInitialBatches() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.transferDTO.stockMovesDOTs.length; ++i) {
        this.queryResourceService
            .getBatchIdUsingGET(this.batchParams)
            .subscribe((data) => {
                this.allBatches[i] = data;
            });
    }
}
```